# Fixed list of possible outputs showing a zero if nothing found for the selected parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

apologies if similar questions have been asked previously. For the below code, I want my report to show all possible options for 'bulk_details' even when there is no data available for the selected 'week' parameter.
Week by week data is compared regularly in our business so all of the possible outcomes in the bulk_details need to be displayed every time the report is ran. I have attached images of the report for week 2235 and 2236 where 2235 has less data than 2236.

Week 2235:

[image: Week 2235 data]

Week 2236:

[image: Week 2236 data]

Current code:

```
WITH a AS (
   SELECT   product_description,
        material_type_code,
        bulk_non_bulk,
        raw_weight_tons,
        financial_net_weight_tons,
        standard_litres,
        sterling_value,
        sterling_cost,
        purchaser_contract_ref,
        supplier_contract_ref,
        purchaser_contract_number,
        supplier_contract_number,
        purchaser_org_code,
        purchaser_org_name,
        purchaser_grouping_code,
        supplier_org_code,
        supplier_org_name,
        supplier_grouping_code,
        sector_code
  ,CASE WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'PURCHASE' AND journal_section_code = 'PURCHASE' THEN 'Purchase'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'BROKER' AND journal_section_code = 'PURCHASE' THEN 'Purchase'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'WASTEBRO' AND journal_section_code = 'PURCHASE' THEN 'Purchase'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'SALEDES' AND journal_section_code = 'SALE' THEN 'Sale'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'BROKER' AND journal_section_code = 'SALE' THEN 'Sale'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'WASTEBRO' AND journal_section_code = 'SALE' THEN 'Sale'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'SALEREC' AND journal_section_code = 'SALE' THEN 'Sale'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'WASTEDIS' AND journal_section_code = 'PURCHASE' THEN 'Waste Disposal'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'WASTESAL' AND journal_section_code = 'SALE' THEN 'Waste Receipt'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'CONSUMABLE' AND journal_section_code = 'PURCHASE' THEN 'Consumable'
  ELSE 'Transfer'
  END AS bulk_type_new
  ,CASE WHEN is_internal = 'I' THEN 'STOCK'
  WHEN journal_bulk_type_code = 'BROKER' THEN 'BROKER'
  ELSE 'STOCK'
  END AS sb
  ,CASE WHEN purchaser_grouping_code = supplier_grouping_code AND sector_code = '' THEN 'INTER'
  WHEN purchaser_grouping_code = 'OLLECO' AND supplier_org_name LIKE ('OLLECO%') AND sector_code = '' THEN 'INTER'
  WHEN purchaser_grouping_code <> supplier_grouping_code AND sector_code = '' THEN '3RDPARTY'
  ELSE sector_code
  END AS    sector_new
        ,journal_business_unit_code
  FROM bi.journal_lines
  WHERE week_number = @Week
  AND material_type_code IN ('UCOP', 'UCOU', 'EFFLUENT')
  ), [data] AS (
  SELECT    product_description
        ,material_type_code
        ,bulk_non_bulk
        ,raw_weight_tons
        ,financial_net_weight_tons
        ,standard_litres
        ,sterling_value
        ,sterling_cost
        ,purchaser_contract_ref
        ,supplier_contract_ref
        ,purchaser_contract_number
        ,supplier_contract_number
        ,purchaser_org_code
        ,purchaser_org_name
        ,purchaser_grouping_code
        ,supplier_org_code
        ,supplier_org_name
        ,supplier_grouping_code
        ,sector_code
        ,bulk_type_new
        ,sb
        ,sector_new
  ,CASE WHEN bulk_type_new IN ('Sale', 'Waste Receipt') THEN purchaser_org_name
  ELSE supplier_org_name
  END AS purchaser_supplier
  ,CASE WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - NB - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - NB - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - NB - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - B - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - B - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - B - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - NB - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - NB - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - NB - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - B - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - B - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Purchase - B - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - NB - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - NB - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - NB - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - B - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - B - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - B - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - NB - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - NB - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - NB - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - B - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - B - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'PURCHASE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Purchase - B - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Sale - NB - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Sale - NB - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Sale - NB - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Sale - B - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Sale - B - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Sale - B - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Sale - NB - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Sale - NB - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Sale - NB - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Stock - Sale - B - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Stock - Sale - B - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'STOCK' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Stock - Sale - B - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Sale - NB - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Sale - NB - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Sale - NB - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Sale - B - InterCo - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Sale - B - InterCo - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new = 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Sale - B - InterCo - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Sale - NB - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Sale - NB - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'NB' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Sale - NB - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOU' THEN 'Broker - Sale - B - 3rd Party - UCOU'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'UCOP' THEN 'Broker - Sale - B - 3rd Party - UCOP'
  WHEN bulk_type_new = 'SALE' AND sector_new <> 'INTER' AND bulk_non_bulk = 'B' AND sb = 'BROKER' AND material_type_code = 'EFFLUENT' THEN 'Broker - Sale - B - 3rd Party - EFFLUENT'
  ELSE NULL
  END AS    bulk_details
        ,journal_business_unit_code
  FROM a
  WHERE bulk_type_new IN ('Sale', 'Purchase' ,'Transfer')
  ), [default] AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT   product_description
                ,material_type_code
                ,bulk_non_bulk
                ,0 AS raw_weight_tons
                ,0 AS financial_net_weight_tons
                ,0 AS standard_litres
                ,0 AS sterling_value
                ,0 AS sterling_cost
                ,purchaser_contract_ref
                ,supplier_contract_ref
                ,purchaser_contract_number
                ,supplier_contract_number
                ,purchaser_org_code
                ,purchaser_org_name
                ,purchaser_grouping_code
                ,supplier_org_code
                ,supplier_org_name
                ,supplier_grouping_code
                ,sector_code    
                ,bulk_type_new
                ,sb
                ,sector_new
                ,purchaser_supplier
                ,bulk_details
                ,journal_business_unit_code
  FROM [data]
  WHERE bulk_details IS NOT NULL
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM [data]
  WHERE journal_business_unit_code = @Business
  AND bulk_details IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM [default]
  ORDER BY bulk_details
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need a distinct list of all possible values. You might be able to get this from existing data but judging by your query, I would guess you can't.

So, create a new table, add all the options in from your case statement's 'THEN' expression which is what I assume you need (e.g. 'Stock - Purchase - NB - InterCo - UCOP', 'Stock - Purchase - NB - InterCo - EFFLUENT', etc...)

Then in your main query, just start with this table and left join you existing query to it, so the end of the statement like look something like this...

```
SELECT *
    FROM myNewTable x 
        LEFT JOIN (  SELECT *
                     FROM [data]
                     WHERE journal_business_unit_code = @Business
                     AND bulk_details IS NOT NULL
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT *
                     FROM [default]) y 
        ON x.myNewListOf_bulk_type = y.bulk_details
     ORDER BY bulk_details
```

Comment: Cheers Alan, i'll give that a go.